# VSCode: Automatically open .html files in one window and .ts in the other

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm writing Angular2 in VSCode. I split the editor window in two and keep all **.html** files on the right and all **.ts** files on the left.

It would be great to automate this, so that when I double click in the file browser the file is opened in the 'type appropriate' window split.

How can I configure or extend VSCode to do this?

[image]

Comment: This really had nothing to do with angular. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Yes and no. Any web dev language where code-files come in pairs of html and /something/ would benefit. So, it's probably applicable to all languages that have this organisation including the one in my example (Angular). Unfortunately I couldn't find a suitably generic tag such as 'web-development-environment'. Also, other Angular developers trying to use VSCode may well be interested in this because of the specific way Angular separates the template code from the ts.

Comment: It would be 'angular' related if somebody had written a BigAngularVSCodeExtension which just happened to have this as a feature. I'd really love to see this, but

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't live without the extension [**angular2-switcher**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher) which adds the following navigations

- <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>**`U`**</kbd> - Go to `.ts`
- <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>**`I`**</kbd> - Go to `.css`
- <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>**`O`**</kbd> - Go to `.html`
- <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>**`P`**</kbd> - Go to `.spec.ts`

<sup>* Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on mac</sup>

Hopefully someday it'll support split screen too

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for! This is awesome :)

Comment: Just discovered (nearly 5 years later): If you go to `File > Settings` and search for `Angular` (see the screenshot in the answer by @RoundRock) then this extension has an option `Open Side By Side`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that today, unless you create a new extension.

But, with [file-ext-switcher extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohannesRudolph.file-ext-switcher) you can open the *related* file using a keybinding, which is great. It worth take a look.

Comment: This extension is last updated in 2018.

Comment: Does it works in current VS Code release (1.75)? If not, you could open an issue in extension's repo and ask for an update. Or maybe today, there is a new extension that works better than this one

Answer (score 1):

You can link auto html opening for component ts file in the settings menu like this:

[image: settings example]

Comment: Do you know what extension this is? I don't see this one under `Angular Language Service`

Answer (score 0):

If are working on angular+.net core then below extension is must have to switch.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.switcher